# Is there a node.js module that can determine Geolocation of an IP?

Tags: javascript, node.js, geolocation, ip, geoip

Give an IP, is there a node.js module that can determine what city and state it is in?

Comment: Downvoted for "shows no research effort" as a web search for "node.js geoip" or "node.js geolocation" would immediately find the relevant modules.

Comment: This question comes up when I google now ...

Answer (score 12):

Have you looked at the [node.js modules page](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules)?

It lists [GeoIP](https://github.com/kuno/GeoIP) and [node-geoip](https://github.com/strange/node-geoip) and [node-maxmind](https://github.com/gyordanov/node-maxmind) and [node-maxmind-native](https://github.com/roymap/node-maxmind-native).

Comment: that page has been deprecated and I found this one that looks better than all the above: https://github.com/bluesmoon/node-geoip

Answer (score 1):

I've found the [node-maxmind](https://github.com/runk/node-maxmind) to be the most feature complete and easy to use module. You need to download the files from the maxmind [download page](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/), and then you can use it like this:

```
maxmind = require 'maxmind'
maxmind.init('GeoLiteCity.dat')
maxmind.getLocation('67.188.232.131')

{ countryCode: 'US',
  countryName: 'United States',
  region: 'CA',
  city: 'Mountain View',
  postalCode: '94043',
  latitude: 37.41919999999999,
  longitude: -122.0574,
  dmaCode: 0,
  areaCode: 0,
  metroCode: 0,
  regionName: 'California' }
```

An alternative to using a module, which usually requires you to install a geolocation database and regularly update it, is to use a geolocation API. One such service is my own, http://ipinfo.io. Here's an example of calling that using the excellent request module:

```
request = require 'request'
request.get('http://ipinfo.io/67.188.232.131', {json: true}, (e, r) -> console.log r.body)

{ ip: '67.188.232.131',
  hostname: 'c-67-188-232-131.hsd1.ca.comcast.net',
  city: 'Mountain View',
  region: 'California',
  country: 'US',
  loc: '37.4192,-122.0574',
  org: 'AS7922 Comcast Cable Communications, Inc.',
  postal: '94043' }
```

See http://ipinfo.io/developers for more details.

Comment: I've tried that but switched over to [`node-maxmind-db`](https://github.com/PaddeK/node-maxmind-db) because it has both sync *and* async API, same method calls support IPv4 *and* IPv6, and it works with the newer MaxMind format.